# How to make CORS request using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.readFile = function(url){

    var doc = new XMLHttpRequest();
    doc.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (doc.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (doc.responseText == undefined)
                return;
            $scope.loglines += doc.responseText;
        }
    }
    doc.open("GET", url, true);


    doc.send();
}
```

this is the code i used to get data from same origin using angularJS. how could i impore this to get data fron cross domain

Comment: use a `url` that is in a different domain - and voilà - you're making a cross origin request

Answer (score 0):

To get data from cross domain, you can't do anything on client side, however you can set CORS on server side so that server allows you to send a cross origin request.

One other bad solution is to disable chrome same origin policy.

[Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)